# SWT AuthenticationListener Eclipse

Tags: authentication, browser, swt, listener

Has anyone ever actually used the AuthenticationListener class in SWT? I downloaded the zip file named "eclipse-jee-galileo-M7-win32.zip" and according to the eclipse site this listener is available as of M6. When I open my project in the IDE this class is not there, nor is any other Authentication class (i.e addAuthenticationListener, AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationListener, etc). It is supposed to be part of the "org.eclipse.swt.browser.*" library.

Am I missing something? need to update libraries somehow? Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the wrong zip turns out. I wanted the file "swt-3.5M6-win32-win32-x86.zip" which is just the updated SWT project, which does contain the required class files. I replaced the older swt with the files in this zip and all works fine.